# How can I add fields to an OpenFile/SaveFile dialog in C#/.NET/WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dialog, openfiledialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customizing OpenFileDialog in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106120/customizing-openfiledialog-in-net)

I need some extra information, such as formatting, when opening/saving files. This cannot be deduced from the file's name and extension. I would like to put a ComboBox with the supported formats right into the Microsoft.Win32.OpenFile/SaveFile dialogs. How can I do this without re-creating the dialogs from scratch?

Comment: Google "Customizing Open File Dialog C#"

Comment: Take a look at weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/11/10/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-6-_1320_-The-New-File-Dialogs.aspx

Comment: @Shaks Your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Edited - Just copy and paste. Also, you might be interested in this link as well. I guess this is a different approach. - "www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy"

Comment: @Shaks Your first link still doesn't work.

Comment: @Shaks It may have something to do with underscores italicizing text since "1320" is in italics both times.

Comment: It has been taken from [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/windowsuidevelopment/thread/1ffc2be4-3af2-4e4e-ac9a-b45ae026a210) blog. I am not sure why this doesn't work when I put it in the comments -

Comment: @Shaks try putting the link between backticks (`).